# Tracking isotope clicks with Google Analytics?

Tags: views, google-analytics

Is there a way to track the clicks of the views isotope header through Google Analytics?

If so how would I set that up? Where would I put the file or code and in what type of file and how would that code be set up?

I'm using:
Drupal 7
Views module 
Views isotope module
Google analytics module

Comment: On your JS file (custom theme or module) bind click event to the element you wish to track and push the event using GA API on the event's handler. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#intro). 
There is a great module for that already [Google Analytics Event Tracking](https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_et)

Just enable both the main and the example module included so you can try it out.
In the selectors array you can define wich element you want to track (e.g. a#logo)
By setting `'label' => '!test'` you can test if the click works (will show an alert box)

```
$selectors = array(
array(
  'event' => 'mousedown',
  'selector' => 'a#logo',
  'category' => 'Home Link',
  'action' => 'click',
  'label' => 'Logo',
  'value' => 0,
  'noninteraction' => TRUE,
),
```

Comment: Brilliant! will try this later tonight. Will i have to duplicate the code above for each item within a menu? or can i use the overall div wrapper as the selector and it will separate which menu link was clicked? I am wondering because more items will be automatically generated at times from autocomplete taxonomy.

Comment: You can use a overall class to target the menu links and by setting label => !text you get the name of the menu item (similar to jQuery .text())